# Gtk3.0 Gtkbuttons and junctions sides

Tags: python, gtk3

I'm trying to align many GtkButton with junction sides but the result is not what I want some help please

my code: it is a python code for Gtk3.0 (3.6) I'm on ubuntu 13.04

```
import gi.repository
from gi.repository import Gtk

def dest(widget):
    widget.destroy()
    Gtk.main_quit()


win = Gtk.Window(Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL)
hbox = Gtk.Box()
bt0 = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Zero")
bt1 = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("One")
bt2 = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Two")
bt0.get_style_context().set_junction_sides(Gtk.JunctionSides.RIGHT)
bt1.get_style_context().set_junction_sides(Gtk.JunctionSides.LEFT|Gtk.JunctionSides.RIGHT)
bt2.get_style_context().set_junction_sides(Gtk.JunctionSides.LEFT)
win.connect("destroy", dest)
hbox.pack_start(bt0, False, False, 0)
hbox.pack_start(bt1, False, False, 0)
hbox.pack_start(bt2, False, False, 0)
win.add(hbox)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just add the linked style class to the parent container:

```
import gi.repository
from gi.repository import Gtk

def dest(widget):
    widget.destroy()
    Gtk.main_quit()

win = Gtk.Window(Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL)
hbox = Gtk.Box()
hbox.get_style_context().add_class(Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_LINKED)
bt0 = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Zero")
bt1 = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("One")
bt2 = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Two")
win.connect("destroy", dest)
hbox.pack_start(bt0, False, False, 0)
hbox.pack_start(bt1, False, False, 0)
hbox.pack_start(bt2, False, False, 0)
win.add(hbox)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```